# For CDF does it make any difference if $y=g(x)$ is monotonic versus strictly monotonic?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

Given a **strictly monotonic function** $y=g(x)$, with inverse function $x=h(y)=g^{-1}(y)$:

- if y=g(x) is **strictly increasing** then:

$$F_Y(Y) = F_X\Big(h(y)\Big)$$

- if y=g(x) is **strictly decreasing** then:

$$F_Y(Y) = 1 - F_X\Big(h(y)\Big)$$

---

Can I also say:

Given a **monotonic function** $y=g(x)$, with inverse function $x=h(y)=g^{-1}(y)$:

- if y=g(x) is **monotonically increasing** then:

$$F_Y(Y) = F_X\Big(h(y)\Big)$$

- if y=g(x) is **monotonically decreasing** then:

$$F_Y(Y) = 1 - F_X\Big(h(y)\Big)$$

---

When I look at wikipedia's definition of **strictly monotonic**, it says that the function will never take on a constant value.

however,  an ordinary **monotonic** function implies that the function can sometime take on a constant value.

I'm a little bit confused because the probability textbook doesn't make a clear distinction between **strictly monotonic functions** and **ordinary monotonic** functions with regards to CDD, and seems to mix them together as if they are the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

A function that is monotonic but not strictly monotonic, and thus constant on an interval, doesn't have an inverse.